# Issues installing Vim color scheme

Tags: vim, settings

This is my first attempt at installing a color scheme for Vim, and I haven't found it very beginner-friendly at all, so perhaps I'll write a guide afterwards for others in my position.
I'm connected to my school's programming server via SSH, and I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) for installing Vundle, [these instructions](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox/wiki/Installation) for adding the gruvbox color scheme plugin, and I did a 'wget' command in my .vim/colors folder to git the [gruvbox repo](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox).

So now I've got a .vimrc file that [looks like this](https://gyazo.com/57ad3dc84183fc8e5607db3c13338893). I then ran the command 'vim +PluginInstall +qall' and it appeared to do something. I restarted the SSH by exiting and reconnecting, and nothing changed at all.

Comment: add `syntax on` before line `colorscheme gruvbox` in your *vimrc*.

Comment: As explanation, `syntax on` will turn on reg exp groups and `colorscheme gruvbox` will source the color script that maps those groups to colors

Answer (score 0):

If you want the new color scheme to take effect. Just create a directory called `colors` under your `~/.vim`, and then move the color scheme file into the `colors` folder. For example, move `solarized.vim` into `~/.vim/colors`. After that, you will see your vim color scheme change.